# Problem saving Facebook images using Paperclip on Rails 3 due to duplicates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, paperclip

I am using the paperclip gem with Omniauth (with Facebook) in a Rails 3 app. All the profile pictures are saved to Amazon S3.

Now the problem I am encountering is that many of the images are saved as `stringio.txt`, resulting in duplicated images. That means, some of my users have profile images that are not their own.

It seems that these images also occur when the image itself is more than 10kb.

So far I've tried saving directly using `open-uri`

`self.avatar = open(omniauth['user_info']['image'].sub("square","large"))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found this solution :

In the model where I have the paperclip image

```
before_post_process :transliterate_file_name

private

  def transliterate_file_name
    extension = 'JPG'
    filename = photo_file_name
    self.photo.instance_write(:file_name, "#{filename}.#{extension}")
  end
```

It work well but in my case, I also have images from regular forms, so I think it's weird to do that. If all the pictures are from Facebook, it will be perfect.

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative in Paperclip >= 3.1.4 is this (instead of using open-uri)

```
  def avatar_remote_url=(url_value)
    self.avatar = URI.parse(url_value)
    # Assuming url_value is http://example.com/photos/face.png
    # avatar_file_name == "face.png"
    # avatar_content_type == "image/png"
    @avatar_remote_url = url_value
  end
```

via https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Attachment-downloaded-from-a-URL

Answer (score 2):

Just hash the filename using `Digest::MD5.hexdigest` in combination with some random value and maybe a timestamp.

Comment: Good idea! I'll give that a shot and report back shortly! Thanks you!